# Want to Disable the Background When Pass the Scroll on Web Page and it Display Background Image

Tags: html, macos, scroll, overscroll

[Screen Shot of the Scrolling Pass the Bottom of the page on MAC](http://cl.ly/image/0q2x0d0T073X)
Want to Disable the Background which Appear when we pass the Scroll on Web Page and reaches it end and it Display Default Background Image.

Want to stop the scrolling when it reaches the End of the page.

Appear on Most Mac Seeing it on Mac OS 10.8.2 and Two Revision Below.